# Is it possible to escape being trapped in an invincible humanoid 'shell'?

Tags: magic, modern-age, escape

My world was created by beings who eschewed physical bodies in favor of enormous blocks of stone to show off their creative potential. There's 12 of them, and together they make Earth and everything in it and live in a Garden of Eden of sorts (a lot of bible imagery here). However, one of them decides to create the perfect body for himself. The details here aren't too important for the question, but anyway this Monolith (as the beings are called, due to their rocky homes) causes quite a ruckus with his body, destroying much of what the other Monoliths strived to create, and thus the others work together to suppress his power by containing him in a humanoid body. They then force the offending party to be the gatekeeper of their little garden for a while, but eventually they release him into the world to do as he pleases in his suppressed form. To stay consistent with the biblical references, let's say they released him about 2000 years ago.

Obviously the Gatekeeper's main goal now is to escape his body so he can use his powers again.

A few notes/ideas:

1. The body was made by 11 Monoliths, so needless to say it would require a tremendous amount of magical power to destroy the body and release the Gatekeeper from his prison - on the scale of supernovas or other cosmic phenomena.
2. The story's timeline takes place between 1 A.D. and ~2015 A.D., so the Gatekeeper needs to find a way to escape by or before the modern age.
3. The Gatekeeper himself still has access to his creationist abilities, but the body works to severely reduce the effectiveness of any magic he uses. This means he can still create exact copies of inanimate objects, machinery of his own design, or even a living creature, provided that he puts in months or even years of uninterrupted effort. HOWEVER,
4. The Monoliths are supremely intelligent and capable of mind control/ESP, and the body does not inhibit the Gatekeeper's train of thought in any way (though it will limit mind control or other mind-related powers if he attempts them). Thus he is one very smart cookie.
5. The Gatekeeper does not need to eat or sleep and both he and his body are functionally immortal; he becomes tired only by using his magic for extended periods (2 hours of rest for every 1 hour of continuous magic work). He can work for up to a ten years uninterrupted before requiring rest, enough time to create one complex life form (e.g. a dragon or similar large and sentient being).
6. The Monoliths later created other sentient beings similar in power to the Gatekeeper to take his place. There are about 100 of them, and none of them have any preconceived opinions about his quest (i.e. they neither approve nor disapprove at the time of his release). Their only job is to guard the garden from intruders, and otherwise they can think and act freely.
7. The Gatekeeper is allowed to come and go from the garden as he pleases, but any interaction with the lookalikes and/or the environment while in the garden is under intense scrutiny by the Monoliths, and actions which appear to damage their work (including his body) are grounds for exile and/or loss of powers.

So, for the main question: given the time frame and the constraints above, **is it possible for the Gatekeeper to escape?**

EDIT: Thanks for the feedback. To clarify, only the Gatekeeper, the other lookalikes, and the Monoliths have access to magic; however, any of them could work to create another magical being if they so chose (with great effort). The rest of Earth completely normal in this sense.

Comment: The world itself is identical in every way to earth as we know it in an given era? Aka besides the Gatekeeper's own "godly" powers (and those of the 100 other dudes) there is no magic system or anything of the sort? Plus, about the 100 other guys... you say they don't care either way if he escapes or doesn't... could he get them to help him out or will they refuse any such attempt in a bid to stay neutral?

Comment: This is a classical "too story based" question. There is no one objectively right answer because you (the author) can make anything happen. The answer doesn't depend on any laws of science or special feature of your world, but only on the creativity of the author. For more details about what is on topic and what is not, please have a look at the [help].

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE. When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture.The purpose of this site is to help you build worlds (rules & systems) not tell a story (circumstances, choices, & plot). As written, this appears to be more about telling a story than creating the rules for your world and testing their consistency. According to our [help/on-topic], Qs must be specific and answerable. This appears to be neither. What specific non-plot problem do you have?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've clarified the question a bit and added some details in the notes to make answering more direct.